# Set DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ItemHeight

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`; because the rows are wrapped on another column (`.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True`), the row heights are not the same as the automatic `.ItemHeight` when `DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal`.

To prevent odd resizing behaviour when the `ComboBox` is shown I am trying to manually draw the `ComboBox` during the `EditingControlShowing` event:

```
Private Sub dgv_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv.EditingControlShowing

        Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)

        If cb IsNot Nothing Then

            For Each code In CheckCodes
                cb.Items.Add(code.Key)
            Next

            cb.ItemHeight = dgv.CurrentRow.Height
            cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed

        End If

    End Sub
```

The odd resizing behaviour:

[image]
[image]

When the dropdown is shown, it resizes to the height of the item (in this case, about half the height of the row).

However, two problems:

- The ComboBox that is shown is blank, despite definitely being populated with items
- When selecting off the ComboBox, a DataError is given: `System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid`

What am I doing wrong here?

Alternatively, is there a simpler way to set the `.ItemHeight` of the ComboBox created by the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What do you mean by *`To prevent odd resizing behaviour when the ComboBox is shown`*?

Comment: I have added some screenshots of the resizing behaviour. It is not very easy to explain though.

Comment: `cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`: this implies that the ComboBox Items are drawn by code you have to provide, using the `DrawItem` event. If you don't have such code, the ComboBox won't show anything, because the Items are not drawn. Don't set the Item height. Also, you're adding Items to the ComboBoxes each time the Editing control is shown. You'll end up with a really long list of repeated items.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, this is a step in the right direction. I've setup my .DrawItem event however it doesn't seem to trigger... The event is: `Private Sub cb_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cb.DrawItem`, presumably I'm not creating the ComboBox correctly?

Comment: You have to use a custom DataGridViewColumn if you want to draw the items manually.